# How to connect two object with line and match the object in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I want to match the two object, when object match then line will be green after touch if the object does not match then line will be red.

Please check [this link](http://dc311.4shared.com/img/CjyAgNo4/s7/140dde6f338/Screen_Shot_2013-09-02_at_2253.png?async&rand=0.6496789942029864)

I want exactly the same but have no idea how to do this.

The line will be the one at a time , line start with black, if the answer will be the right then line will be green and if the answer will wrong then line will be red. And line end.

another line will create when we touch another object. And same process will be done.

Any idea or suggestions would be highly welcome.

Comment: There are many ways to do it, like you can you the tag propery of views(i assumes that all is done using the views).

Comment: @nisha singh use touches began and touches end methods and check first touch button tag and check last touch button tag and compair that two tag's.